# Excel VBA Clear formats when value is 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a report in which there are some cells with null values. When my code applies the number format to null cells, it shows up as `0%` for blank values. I added a code that then removes any values and format that show up as `0%`, but it takes a really long time to run (30 sec or so) and sometimes crashes Excel.

Code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("v11:ay9000")
    If cell = 0 Then cell.ClearFormats
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I would appreciate any help with the speed of the code.

Comment: The reason why it takes over 30 seconds is because you are cycling through a ton of cell columns `V:AY`. 30 seconds is generous! lol. Is the main crux of your question the speed of your code or the implementation of your code?

Comment: That code doesn't 'removes any values', it only clears formats. If the number format is your sole concern, set it to *General*. Are you looking for zeroes or blanks or both? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @medicine_man The overall concern is the speed. If I need to go about another of implementing the code then I definitely am open to that. I just can't have the report taking 30 secs or even crashing. I am trying to make the report as user friendly  for the end user.

Comment: You are trying to edit `(9000-11)*30` cells (269,670 cells). There may be a way to edit your code, or add something, to make it faster, but I would be pretty happy with 30 seconds to be honest with you.

Comment: @user11246173 I am trying to clear the zeros. Initally when I run the the report there are cells that have null values. However, when i apply the format therange the null values get converted to 0% or $0. So therefore I am trying to get the cell to go back to being null/empty. There are multiple columns and I am applying different number formats to each of the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

You're trying to improve the time it takes to repair your initial problem. Instead, you should just set the correct number format in the first place.

```
Range("v11:ay9000").numberformat = "0%;-0%;;"
```

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of **"0%;-0%;;"**. VBA Help wasn't helpful.

Comment: A custom number format consists of four parts separated by 3 semi-colons; positive numbers, negative numbers, zeroes and text. By providing the format for positive and negative then intentionally omitting the zero and text format any zeroes or text will not be displayed. Look at an Accounting style format to see how zeroes can be converted to hyphens.

Comment: [Review guidelines for customizing a number format](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/review-guidelines-for-customizing-a-number-format-c0a1d1fa-d3f4-4018-96b7-9c9354dd99f5)